# Get attachment/image info in JS

Tags: images

Is there a specific method to get attachment/image info in JS?
I have an attachment id and before I use any

```
add_action("wp_ajax_get_image_info", "get_image_info");
```

I would like to see if there is a native method for doing this trough JS only.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Long story short, you can get info about an attachment by using `wp.media.attachment()` function. This will give you complete data as long as this attachment is already loaded by another script or an `wp.media()` popup.

If the data is not yet loaded, you can load it using `.fetch()` method on attachment, which works because it is a [`Backbone.Collection`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch). It is a `Collection` because an attachment may have multiple selected files in it.

```
// preload your attachment
wp.media.attachment(ID).fetch().then(function (data) {
  // preloading finished
  // after this you can use your attachment normally
  wp.media.attachment(ID).get('url');
});
```

---

Easy way of doing preloading:

```
function preloadAttachment(ID, callback) {
  // if it doesn't have URL we probably have to preload it
  if (wp.media.attachment(ID).get('url')) {
    wp.media.attachment(ID).fetch().then(function () {
      callback(wp.media.attachment(ID);
    });

    return;
  }

  callback(wp.media.attachment(ID));
}

// USAGE:
preloadAttachment(10, function (attachment) {
  console.log(attachment.get('url'));
  console.log(wp.media.attachment(10).get('url')); // this also works
})
```

---

And that's how you will want to go about preloading more than one *attachment*, in a single AJAX request.

```
// An array of attachments you may want to preload
var attachment_ids = [10, 11, 12, 13];
wp.media.query({ post__in: attachment_ids })
  .more()
  .then(function () {
    // You attachments here normally
    // You can safely use any of them here
    wp.media.attachment(10).get('url');
  })
```

Note the fact that the AJAX request performed by `wp.media.query()` is paginated. If you need a robust solution for loading lots and lots of attachments you should go about parsing each page with [`hasMore()` and `more()` methods](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5f4497f0af1f18137e1f109e5b10f4a30ffb49b5/wp-includes/js/media-models.js#L708-L740).

Disclaimer:

I have used this method before finding out about `wp.media.query` but it has the penalty of making one request per preloaded attachment. But it also has a nice feature -- it doesn't make any request if all of the attachments that need to be preloaded are already in the fetched state.

```
function preloadMultipleAttachments(attachment_ids) {
    // I'd rather use Promise.all() here but they do not work with
    // jQuery deferreds :/
    if (jQuery.when.all===undefined) {
        jQuery.when.all = function(deferreds) {
            var deferred = new jQuery.Deferred();
            $.when.apply(jQuery, deferreds).then(
                function() {
                    deferred.resolve(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
                },
                function() {
                    deferred.fail(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
                });

            return deferred;
        }
    }

    return jQuery.when.all(
        attachment_ids.filter(function (attachment_id) {
            return ! wp.media.attachment(attachment_id).get('url');
        }).map(function (id) {
            return wp.media.attachment(id).fetch();
        })
    );
},
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit as how it helps in addition to posting the code

Comment: @bravokeyl Done.

Comment: Updated to include a way to preload more than one attachment in a single AJAX request. Will save you some payload passing down the way.

Comment: @AndreiGlingeanu, Do you know is there way to get attachment by url instead of id. like this `wp.media.attachment(url)`

Comment: @TigranBabajanyan just write an AJAX action by yourself & return the correct attachment using [`wp_prepare_attachment_for_js()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_prepare_attachment_for_js)

Answer (score 0):

Jetpack has a JSON API that allows you to query pretty much everything in a given install. http://jetpack.me/support/json-api/

Comment: we are not jetpack users , Unyson rather than anything else.